# Use both send and pickup directory method for SMTP mailSetting

Tags: c#, smtp, web-config, mailsettings

Current system that I working on has a email sending function with this configuration in Web.config as below

```
<mailSettings>
    <!-- Method#1: Configure smtp server credentials -->
    <smtp from="some-email@gmail.com">
        <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="some-email@gmail.com" password="valid-password" />
    </smtp>
    <!-- Method#2: Dump emails to a local directory -->
    <smtp from="some-email@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <network host="localhost" />
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="~/App_Data/EmailPickup" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

As the config shown about there is 2 method, but it only able to enable 1 method in a time, else it will cause error when i try to run the system.

**Question**: it there any config or setting can make both of the method work at the same time?
I want it send the email as well as pickup the email and drop it into the folder i specific on.

I was able to manually create a file with [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2) and save into folder but it require extra code to handle it.